# PHP get div that contains a word

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get the divs that contain [Release] at the bottom of this page http://mpgh.net/forum/175-crossfire-hacks-cheats/.

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("http://mpgh.net/forum/175-crossfire-hacks-cheats/");

$check_hash = preg_match('#<div class=\"inner\"> <h3 class=\"threadtitle\"> <a href="\.*?\" id=\".*?\"><img class=\".*?\" src=\".*?\" alt=\"Go to first new post\" title=\"Go to first new post\"></a> <img src=\".*?\" alt=\".*?\" border=\"0\" title=\".*?\"> <span class=\"prefix understate\"> <span style=\".*?\"><b>(.*?)</b></span> </span> <a class=\"title threadtitle_unread\" href=\"(.*?)\" id=\".*?\">(.*?)</a> </h3> <div class=\"threadmeta\"> <div class=\"author\"> <span class=\"label\">Started by&nbsp;<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"(.*?)\" class=\"username understate\" title=\"Started by (.*?) on .*?\">.*?</a>.*?</span> </div> </div> </div>#', $text, $match);

print_r($match);
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, now I'm confused because I can't find a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't want to use regex for parsing html...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):
Try this code:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://mpgh.net/forum/175-crossfire-hacks-cheats/');
$ret = $html->find('div[class=inner]',0);
echo $ret->innertext;
```